# Is レジ used as a contraction of registration?

Tags: translation, slang, contractions

The page [自分で手続きワーキングホリデー](http://jibunde-workingholiday.com/car.html) seems to be using レジ as short for "registration". But as far as I know, レジ is used as short for "[cash] register", not "registration", and the Australian English slang for "registration" is "rego", not "regie" or "redgie".

Can レジ be used as a contraction for "registration"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, I have never heard of レジ  being used for "registration". Sounds like an Australian has translated this page using "レジ" like Australia uses "rego" for "registration".

In any case , レジ will 99% of the time be associated with a cash register.